# Flask: when to use session vs. storing user data in db?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application and need to store users' place when they navigate the content.

For example, I have a route like this: `@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>', defaults={'category': 'new'})`

The content is organized such that you page through articles under a category: starting at 0, then 1, and so forth. The URL for article number 3 would look like: `articles/<category>/3`

I'd like to save users' place so that if they leave the site after visiting article 3, when they navigate to the articles page they'll land on `articles/<category>/3`, rather than `articles/<category>/0`.

What is the best way to achieve this? Currently, I've modeled the data in the database so there is a column that looks like `category_article_last_visited` (integer). I'm able to store this data as a user browses the site, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it when they return to the articles page.

What I've tried:

- `@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>', defaults={'category': 'new', 'article_number':current_user.category_article_last_visited})`, but I get an error that there is no such attribute.
- Checking `current_user.category_article_last_visited` in the routes function and using the article number. This renders the correct content, but doesn't change the URL, which won't work.
- Redirecting users if they have a value for `current_user.category_article_last_visited`. This doesn't seem to yield any change.

I am curious if storing in the db (assigning the value, db.commit(), etc.) is the right path, or if I should explore flask-sessions more. I need this information to persist across sessions, so that if a user logs out, clears cookies, uses a different device, etc. it is still available. I may also perform analytics on these values in the future.

- Is the method I've described above the best way to achieve this? Is flask-sessions or something else preferable?
- If the method outlined above is best, how do I correctly route this information so that users are directed to the page they left off, and the URL is changed appropriately?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the solution I decided on:

- I update the paths of nav links throughout the site, so instead of `/articles/<category>/0` it's `/articles/<category>/current_user.article_number_last_visited`
- Since not all users have visited articles in every category, I added default routing logic, similar to:

```
@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/', defaults={'article_number': 0})
@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

This routes users correctly even if current_user.article_number is null.

I believe this will also work if the user is not logged in (and therefore there will be no `article_number` attribute). I haven't checked this case out thoroughly though because in my use case users have to be logged in to view content.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the redirect solution, it is more clear.

I would add an if statement at the beginning of the route-function and if there is data for this user, i would redirect to that page. For example:

```
@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>', defaults={'category': 'new'})
def routefunc():
    if current_user.category_article_last_visited !=0: #or whatever your column keeps for empty data
        return redirect ('/articles/'+yourcategory +'/'+ current_user.category_article_last_visited #as string
```

This must be combined with some other functionality, to avoid infinitive redirection to this route:

Option 1:

You can add another variable in the route that will have specific value on these redirections and will ignore this if statement. For example:

```
@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>/<check>', defaults={'category': 'new'})
def routefunc():
if current_user.category_article_last_visited !=0 and check!=1: return redirect ('/articles/'+yourcategory +'/'+ current_user.category_article_last_visited+'/1')
```

However in this case you must add this variable (with some other value different from 1) to all of your urls-hrefs etc and it will make your urls more "dirty". It would be effective for a small app, but i would avoid it for a big app/website with multiple internal links.

Option 2:

You could add one more column in your database table that will be 1/0 depending on when user visitis this route, directly or from redirection. In this case you must add  a couple of queries to check and/or update this value before-after redirection.

Option 3:

You could create another similar route that will only handle redirections, and produce the same results (same html) but without the if statement. For example:

```
@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>', defaults={'category': 'new'})
    def routefunc():
        if current_user.category_article_last_visited !=0: #or whatever your column keeps for empty data
            return redirect ('/articles2/'+yourcategory +'/'+ current_user.category_article_last_visited #as string

@main_bp.route2('/articles2/<category>/<article_number>', defaults={'category': 'new'})
    def routefunc():
        return ('yourhtml.html')
```

***Session based approach is not good here, as you want a long term solution.
As you probably have many categories, articles, users, you would better create a separate table specifically for this

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but I'm getting a "redirected too many times" error. Does this approach just set up an infinite loop?

Comment: Hmmm, you are right. There are multiple solutions for this, for example you can add another variable in the route that will have specific value on these redirections and will ignore this if statement. For example:    `@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number/<check>>', defaults={'category': 'new'})
def routefunc():
    if current_user.category_article_last_visited !=0 and check!=1:
return redirect ('/articles/'+yourcategory +'/'+ current_user.category_article_last_visited+'/1'`

However you must add this variable to all of your urls-hrefs etc and it will make your urls>>>

Comment: More "dirty" It would be effective for a small app, but i would avoid it for a big app/website with multiple internal links. It's up to you, what you consider more important (tidiness, simplicity, user experience, etc) and make your choices
Alternatively, you could add one more column in your database table that will be 1/0 depending on when user visitis this route, directly or from redirection. You could also create another similar route that will only handle redirections, and produce the same results (same html) but without the if statement

Comment: I added my comments to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the **best way** to achieve what you want but here's what you could try. Assuming you want to perform some analytics on the data you might want to store it in a database.

You could have a route designed to create a user cookie when a new user visits your page and redirects him to the articles page with the new cookie set:

```py
@main_bp.route('/articles/set_cookie', "GET"])
def set_article_cookie():

    sessionserializer = securecookiesessioninterface().get_signing_serializer(main_bp)
    tempcookie = sessionserializer.dumps(dict(session))
    resp = make_response(redirect('/articles')) 
    resp.set_cookie("user", tempcookie)
    return resp
```

And your existing route in which you check if the user has already visited the page. In which case you will want to check in the database what was the last article he read and redirect him accordingly:

```py
@main_bp.route('/articles/<category>/<article_number>', defaults={'category': 'new'})
def articles(category, article_number):

    # If the user cookie is already set, check if there is some data is the database and redirect to his last article visited 
    cookie = request.cookies
    if "user" in cookie:
        # Retreive the user cookie value and check the database for this value
        return redirect('/articles/' + last_article_visited)

    # Else redirect the user to set_article_cookie
    else:
        return redirect("/set_article_cookie")
```